# Can't access outer class from anonymous class

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't access outer method from inside of anonymous one

```
class MyClass()
{
    fun doSomeStuff()
    {
       for (brandView in holder.brandImages)
       {
           brandView.onClick {
               if (brandView.brandId != null)
               {
                   notifyStateChanged()
               }
           }
       }
    }
    fun notifyStateChanged()
    {
        print("something")
    }
}
```

I got compile time error:

```
Error:(46, 31) org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Don't know how to generate outer expression for class <closure-BrandsBarView$1>
Cause: Don't know how to generate outer expression for class <closure-BrandsBarView$1>
File being compiled and position: (46,31) in C:/Users/piotr/IdeaProjects/MerciIt/app/src/main/java/pl/com/digita/merciit/app/ui/controls/colorswitcher/brandsbar/BrandsBarView.kt
PsiElement: {
                if (brandView.brandId != null)
                {
                    notifyStateChanged()
                    //brandView.setTicked(!brandView.isTicked)
                }
            }
The root cause was thrown at: CodegenContext.java:160
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:299)
(...)
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Just for theoretical discussions:

```
for (brandView in holder.brandImages)
{
    setupBrandView(brandView)
}

fun setupBrandView(brandView: BrandTickerView)
{
    brandView.onClick {brandView.isTicked = !brandView.isTicked; dataChanged?.invoke() }

}
```

Works ok

Comment: If you have a compiler crash such as above, you should report the crash to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com since it is not a code syntax problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In anonymous classes `this` refer to outer class. 
From `object` outer activity must be referred explicitly

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
        text_view.setOnClickListener{ v ->
            this.doActivityStuff()
        }
...
    fun doActivityStuff() {
        // do some stuff
    }
    text_view.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            this.onClick(v) // this refer to onClickListener
            this@MainActivity.doActivityStuff() // this refer to MainActivity
        }
    })
}
```

To help with your situation it'll be nice to see classes hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I added some lines of code to give better context to this snipplets. I've also tried with qualified this with no luck.

Comment: also provide brandView class